# Display of screen is pushed down xamarin.forms android

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Weirdly my display of screen is pushed down for only the MainPage thereafter display fits the screen as it should. I've tried deleting the page and re-adding it but that didn't work either. Does anyone know what could be causing this and how to fix it?

**Here's what it looks like: The black space at the top should not be there**
[image]

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage
    x:Class="LoyaltyWorx.Views.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LoyaltyWorx.Views.Converters"
    xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
    prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
    >
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <local:InvertBooleanConverter x:Key="InvertBooleanConverter" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Image Source="bk3.jpg" Aspect="AspectFill"/>
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Start">
            <!-- top controls -->
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
            <!-- middle controls -->
            <BoxView HeightRequest="430"></BoxView>
            <Button Text="Continue with Facebook" x:Name="LoginBtn" BackgroundColor="#4867aa" TextColor="White" FontFamily="Klavika" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Clicked="LoginBtn_Clicked" />
            <Button Text="Continue with Google  " Command="{Binding GoogleLoginCommand}" BackgroundColor="#d34836" TextColor="White" FontFamily="Klavika" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="End" HorizontalOptions="Center">
            <!-- bottom controls -->
            <Frame OutlineColor="White" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="End" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                    <!-- bottom controls -->
                    <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="0">
                        <Label  
                               Text="Terms and conditions"
                              FontSize="13"
                            TextColor="#71757a"
                            FontAttributes="Bold"
                            x:Name="LblTerms"/>
                        <Label  
                            Text=" and"
                            FontSize="13"
                            TextColor="#71757a"
                            />

                        <Label  
                               Text=" privacy policy"
                            FontSize="13"
                            TextColor="#71757a"
                            FontAttributes="Bold"
                            x:Name="LblPrivacy"/>
                    </StackLayout>

                </StackLayout>
            </Frame>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

App.cs

```
public partial class App : PrismApplication
    {

        public App(IPlatformInitializer initializer = null) : base(initializer) { }


        protected override void OnInitialized()
        { 
            InitializeComponent();
            SetMainPage();
            NavigationService.NavigateAsync("NavigationPage/MainPage?title=Hello%20from%20Xamarin.Forms");
        }

        protected override void RegisterTypes()
        {
            Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<NavigationPage>();
            Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<MainPage>();
        }

        private void SetMainPage()
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Helpers.Settings.Usertoken))
            {
                Application.Current.MainPage = (new Profile());
            }
            else
            {
                MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage())
                { BarBackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#393b3d") };

            }
        }

        public async static Task NavigateToSMS()
        {
            await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new SMS());
        }

        public static void NavigateToProfile()
        {
            Application.Current.MainPage = (new InvalidLogin());
        }
        public static void NavigateToVerified()
        {
            Application.Current.MainPage = (new Profile());
        }

        protected override void OnStart()
        {
            // Handle when your app starts
        }

        protected override void OnSleep()
        {
            // Handle when your app sleeps
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            // Handle when your app resumes
        }
    }
```

Comment: first of all, why do you use stacklayout inside grid instead of using grid rows. you want to overlay image over it but for that better to use absolutelayout around grid and set your image in the middle of the absolutelayout. this is a performance impact. Regarding your problem, try VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" on your Grid.

Comment: Don't think it has anything to do with my layout on xaml, I just deleted it and added a new xaml page with no code from my side and it's the same. I'm assuming something in my app.cs is causing the problem

Comment: If you upgraded xamarin forms package recently, there was some similar issue with one of the or latest forms version, this might cause the problem.

Comment: Try to change the Image `Aspect` Property to `Fill` instead of `AspectFill`. I think this is increasing up the Image view vertically on rendering. You can see it if you enable `Show layout bounds` on developer settings of you Android device.

Answer (score 2):

You have your `MainPage` wrapped in a `NavigationPage` that by default shows the NavigationBar. You can turn it off in your cs code or in your `MainPage.xaml`

cs

```
var mainPage = new MainPage();
MainPage = new NavigationPage(mainPage);
NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(mainPage, false);
```

xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage
    x:Class="LoyaltyWorx.Views.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LoyaltyWorx.Views.Converters"
    xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
    prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
    NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False">
```