# NavigationPage Wrapping causing bug in status bar

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, navigation

I'm experiencing a weird bug when I try to add `Navigation` to my `CropsListPage`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
       xmlns:local="clr-Balloney.Views"
       x:Class="Balloney.Views.MainPage">

   <NavigationPage Icon="carrot.png">
    <x:Arguments>
        <local:CropListPage/>
    </x:Arguments>
   </NavigationPage> 
   <ContentPage Icon="search.png"></ContentPage>

 </TabbedPage>
```

And then it results in..

[image]

If I don't try to envelop it in a `NavigationPage`, it stays normal

[image]

Any idea what's causing this behaviour ? Before trying to hammer my way outta this and hardcoding the size of the status bar in Android, I'm looking for a way to understand the problem and prevent it. Thanks

`MainPage.xaml` working now

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
           xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
           xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Balloney.Views"
           x:Class="Balloney.Views.MainPage">

  <local:CropListPage Icon="carrot.png"/>
  <ContentPage Icon="search.png"></ContentPage>

</TabbedPage>
```

And the `CropList` xaml

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="Balloney.Views.CropListPage">
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding CropsList}" ItemTapped="OnCropTapped">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl}" VerticalOptions="Fill" WidthRequest="50"/>
                    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                        <Label Text="{Binding Specie.Name}"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding HarvestDate}" FontSize="Micro" TextColor="Black"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Location}" FontSize="Micro" TextColor="Chocolate" />
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
</ContentPage>
```

**EDIT:** The error seems to be related to the `ListView` I have inside `CropListPage` because there's no bug when I switch to the `Search icon` Page.

[image]

Comment: I think the navigation page should wrap the tabbed page, not the content pages within the tabbed page.

Comment: @SteveChadbourne Same result if I try that. But I followed the documentation and I'm doing it right. It can wrap navigation pages also

Comment: @SteveChadbourne Check it https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/navigation/tabbed-page/#Populating_a_TabbedPage_with_a_Page_Collection

Comment: Yep you're correct. In fact it specifically says not to wrap a tapped page in a navigation page!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The extra space in your first image is the result of the `NavigationPage` by default showing the Navigation bar, which can be hidden.

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47713030/display-of-screen-is-pushed-down-xamarin-forms-android/47716077#47716077) an example of how to hide it.

Answer (score 1):

Is may be because you have wrapped crop list page in a navigation page so when that is selected you get the nav bar space above.

If you select the second tab, does the space disappear?

If you add a title to crop page does it appear in the large green space?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
       xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Chronocrops.Views"
       x:Class="Chronocrops.Views.MainPage">

   <NavigationPage Icon="carrot.png" Title="Crop List">
    <x:Arguments>
        <local:CropListPage/>
    </x:Arguments>
   </NavigationPage> 
   <ContentPage Icon="search.png"></ContentPage>

 </TabbedPage>
```

Comment: Yes you're right, in the `Search icon page` it stays normal. No, the `Title` remains inside. I will upload a picture. Any ideas to why is this happening just cause I have a `ListView` inside the page ?